# Why $'\0' or $'\x0' is an empty string? Should be the null-character, isn't it?

Tags: string, bash, echo, expansion, dollar-sign

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) allows `$'string'` expansion. My `man bash` says:

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. 
>   The word expands to **`string`**, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. 
>   Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows: 
>             `\a`     alert (bell)        
>             `\b`     backspace           
>             `\e`                         
>             `\E`     an escape character 
>             `\f`     form feed           
>             `\n`     new line            
>             `\r`     carriage return     
>             `\t`     horizontal tab      
>             `\v`     vertical tab        
>             `\`     backslash           
>             `\'`     single quote        
>             `\"`     double quote        
>             `\nnn`   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value **`nnn`** (one to three digits)
>             `\xHH`   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value **`HH`** (one or two hex digits)
>             `\cx`    a control-**`x`** character
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

But **why does [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) not convert `$'\0'` and `$'\x0'` into a null character?** 
Is it documented? Is there a reason? (Is it a feature or a limitation or even a bug?)

```
$ hexdump -c <<< _$'\0'$'\x1\x2\x3\x4_'
0000000   _ 001 002 003 004   _  \n
0000007
```

`echo` gives the expected result:

```
> hexdump -c < <( echo -e '_\x0\x1\x2\x3_' )
0000000   _  \0 001 002 003   _  \n
0000007
```

My bash version

```
$ bash --version | head -n 1
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

**Why `echo $'foo\0bar'` does not behave as `echo -e 'foo\0bar'`?**

Comment: Good question! Maybe it's a Posix thing? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I have been having the same problem while using netcat to test the SGCI interface to a server. The SCGI header has NUL characters. After reading here, especially the suggestion to use pipes, I developed a workaround. I use octal 377 (ASCII 255) where the NUL characters need to be, and then pipe the string through tr just before piping it into netcat xmlreq='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodCall><methodName>system.client_version</methodName><params></params></methodCall>' scgihdr=CONTENT_LENGTH$'\377'${#xmlreq}$'\377'SCGI$'\377'1$'\377' echo -n ${#scgihdr

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a limitation. `bash` does not allow string values to contain interior NUL bytes.

Posix (and C) character strings cannot contain interior NULs. See, for example, the [Posix definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_92) of character string (emphasis added):

> 3.92 Character String
>
> A contiguous sequence of characters **terminated by** and including the **first null byte**.

Similarly, standard C is reasonably explicit about the NUL character in character strings:

> §5.2.1p2 …A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to **terminate** a character string.

Posix explicitly forbids the use of NUL (and `/`) in filenames (XBD 3.170) or in environment variables (XBD 8.1 "... are considered to end with a null byte."

In this context, shell command languages, including bash, tend to use the same definition of a character string, as a sequence of non-NUL characters terminated by a single NUL.

You can pass NULs freely through bash pipes, of course, and nothing stops you from assigning a shell variable to the output of a program which outputs a NUL byte. However, the consequences are "unspecified" according to Posix (XSH 2.6.3 "If the output contains any null bytes, the behavior is unspecified."). In bash, the NULs are removed, unless you insert a NUL into a string using bash's C-escape syntax (`$'\0'`), in which case the NUL will end up terminating the value.

On a practical note, consider the difference between the two following ways of attempting to insert a NUL into the `stdin` of a utility:

```
$ # Prefer printf to echo -n
$ printf $'foo\0bar' | wc -c
3
$ printf 'foo\0bar' | wc -c
7
$ # Bash extension which is better for strings which might contain %
$ printf %b 'foo\0bar' | wc -c
7
```

Comment: Great info. Re: "nothing stops you from assigning a shell variable to the output of a program which outputs a NUL" - it's worth pointing out that the variable's value will invariably be cut off at the first NUL encountered.
Re "if you insert a NUL into a string using one of bash's backslash escape sequences ($'\0'), it will end up terminating the value." - to clarify: inserting `$'\0'` into _another_ string will _not_ terminate the overall string, but simply ignore the `$'\0'`; e.g., `a$'\0'b` -> `ab`; a `\0` _inside_ `$'…'`, however, _will_ cut off that string there; e.g., `$'a\0b'` -> `a`.

Comment: @mklement0: Yeah, I got that wrong two years ago. Thanks. Fixed, now, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Re assigning command output to a variable: Given that `bash` variable values are internally stored as C strings, they can never contain NULs. However, it's worth distinguishing between (a) `var=$(...)`, in which case, as you state, all NULs are simply _stripped_, so the value that is assigned by definition never contains NULs but contains _all other_ characters, and (b) `read -r d '' var < <(....)`, where the input may contain NULs, but `read` won't allow reading past the first NUL and the value is therefore _cut off_ at the first NUL.

Comment: @mklement0: But stopping at the NUL is because you've told `read` to do so with `-d ''`. If a NUL is encountered by `read` and record terminator is a newline (or anything other than a NUL), then the behaviour is consistent with command substitution: the NUL is stripped but the string is not terminated. IOW, read will read past the NUL *unless* you've specified NUL as a terminator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out: it turns out that `read` stripping NULs was [introduced in Bash _4.3.3_](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS). In bash _4.3.2 and below_, `read` never reads past a NUL; for instance, in Bash 3.2.57 `read -r var < <(printf 'a\0b')` assigns just `a` to `$var` - anything after the NUL is dropped.

Comment: @mklement0: Ah, interesting. I think I'll stick with "unspecified" in this answer; `read` isn't really very relevant. (If it were, one would have to look at `printf -v` and other things, which are totally tangential to the OP.)

Comment: Understood. Just to close the tangent: `printf -v` cuts off at the first NUL (in all `bash` versions to date). Final thought: Your examples show the behavior well, but the wording of "unless you insert a NUL into a string using bash's C-escape syntax (`$'\0'`)" still sounds like `a'$'\0'b` (-> `ab`) rather than the intended `$'a\0b'` (-> `a`) to me.

Answer (score 5):

> But why does bash not convert `$'\0'` and `$'\x0'` into a null character?

Because a null character terminates a string.

```
$ echo $'hey\0you'
hey
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a null character, but it depends on what you mean by that.

The null character represents an empty string, which is what you get when you expand it.  It is a special case and I think that is implied by the documentation but not actually stated.

In C binary zero `'\0'` terminates a string and on its own also represents an empty string.  Bash is written in C, so it probably follows from that.

Edit:  POSIX mentions a null string in a number of places.  In the "Base definitions" it defines a null string as:

> **3.146 Empty String (or Null String)** 
>   A string whose first byte is a null byte.