# In a bash script, what would $'\0' evaluate to and why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

In various bash scripts I have come across the following: `$'\0'`

An example with some context:

```
while read -r -d $'\0' line; do
    echo "${line}"
done <<< "${some_variable}"
```

What does $'\0' return as its value? Or, stated slightly differently, what does $'\0' evaluate to and why?

It is possible that this has been answered elsewhere. I did search prior to posting but the limited number of characters or meaningful words in dollar-quote-slash-zero-quote makes it very hard to get results from stackoverflow search or google. So, if there are other duplicate questions, please allow some grace and link them from this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one in unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223823/null-and-escape-characters#223837)

Comment: Also could be considered a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227564/why-0-or-x0-is-an-empty-string-should-be-the-null-character-isnt-it) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Aside: Using `echo` here is very much suboptimal. See the POSIX spec for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html -- it has a *huge* amount of undefined behavior. (Is your string `-n`? Behavior undefined. Does your string contain a backslash literal anywhere? Behavior undefined. And if your string is `-e` or `-E`, then behavior is well-defined by POSIX, but you're likely to have an implementation that defies the standard -- unless you have the `xpg_echo` option set.

Comment: I imagine the level of pedantry and hair-splitting is more than you bargained for in asking this question -- but with all answers taken together, you presumably have a very comprehensive understanding of the matter at hand, or at minimum plenty of places from which to launch further research or follow-up questions. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree. Amidst all the hair-splitting, people were kind and helpful. It was \informative to reading the answers and the comments on each. In total, it has given me a much better understanding of what is happening. In particular, I learned 1) that the `$'\0'` was an ANSI C-quoted string 2) that in Bash strings are NUL terminated. Both of those were new to me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will assume that the word "pedantry" is a reflection of the way you think, a simple look in the mirror if you wish.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, indeed, I was poking a bit of fun at myself above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You have my full permissions to poke at yourself all you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complement [rici's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36587726/45375):

<sup>Note that **this answer is about `bash`**. `ksh` and `zsh` also support `$'...'` strings, but their behavior differs:

* **`zsh` does create and preserve NUL (null bytes) with `$'\0'`**.

* **`ksh`**, by contrast, has the same limitations as `bash`, and *additionally* interprets the first NUL in a command substitution's output as the string terminator (*cuts off* at the first NUL, whereas `bash` *strips* such NULs).</sup>

**`$'\0'` is an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)** that *technically* creates a NUL (`0x0` byte), but ***effectively* results in the empty (null) string (same as `''`)**, because any NUL is interpreted as the (C-style) string *terminator* by Bash in the context of arguments and here-docs/here-strings.

As such, it is **somewhat *misleading* to use `$'\0'`** because it suggests that you can create a NUL this way, when you actually cannot:

- You ***cannot* create NULs** as part of a command **argument** or **here-doc / here-string**, and you ***cannot* store NULs in a variable**:

  - `echo $'a\0b' | cat -v # -> 'a'` - string *terminated* after 'a'
  - `cat -v <<<$'a\0b' # -> 'a'` - ditto
- In the context of **command substitutions**, by contrast, **NULs are *stripped***:

  - `echo "$(printf 'a\0b')" | cat -v # -> 'ab'` - NUL is *stripped*
- However, you ***can* pass NUL** bytes via **files** and **pipes**.

  - `printf 'a\0b' | cat -v # -> 'a^@b'` - NUL is *preserved*, via stdout and pipe
  - Note that it is `printf` that is generating the NUL via its *single-quoted* argument whose escape sequences `printf` then interprets and writes to stdout. By contrast, if you used `printf $'a\0b'`, `bash` would again interpret the NUL as the string terminator up front and pass only `'a'` to `printf`.

If we examine the **sample code**, whose ***intent* is to read the entire input *at once*, across lines** (I've therefore changed `line` to `content`):

```
while read -r -d $'\0' content; do  # same as: `while read -r -d '' ...`
    echo "${content}"
done <<< "${some_variable}"
```

**This will *never* enter the `while` loop body**, because stdin input is provided by a *here-string*, which, as explained, cannot contain NULs.
Note that **`read` actually *does* look for NULs with `-d $'\0'`, even though `$'\0'` is effectively `''`**. <sup>In other words: `read` *by convention* interprets the empty (null) string to mean NUL as `-d`'s option-argument, because NUL itself cannot be specified for technical reasons.</sup>

In the absence of an actual NUL in the input, `read`'s exit code indicates *failure*, so the loop is never entered.

However, **even in the absence of the delimiter, the value is *read***, so to make this code work with a here-string or here-doc, it must be modified as follows:

```
while read -r -d $'\0' content || [[ -n $content ]]; do
    echo "${content}"
done <<< "${some_variable}"
```

However, as @rici notes in a comment, with a *single* (multi-line) input string, there is **no need to use `while` at all**:

```
read -r -d $'\0' content <<< "${some_variable}"
```

This reads the entire content of `$some_variable`, while trimming leading and trailing whitespace (which is what `read` does with `$IFS` at its default value, `$' \t\n'`).
@rici also points out that if such trimming weren't desired, a simple `content=$some_variable` would do.

Contrast this with **input that actually contains NULs**, in which case `while` *is* needed to process each NUL-separated token (but without the `|| [[ -n $<var> ]]` clause); `find -print0` outputs filenames separated by a NUL each):

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    echo "${file}"
done < <(find . -print0)
```

<sup>Note the use of `IFS= read ...` to suppress trimming of leading and trailing whitespace, which is undesired in this case, because input filenames must be preserved as-is.</sup>

Comment: If trimming were not desired, the robust solution would be `content=$some_variable`; all the rest is obfuscation. But I suspect trimming was intentional; it's actually a reasonably clever implementation of trim, except for the `while` of course.

Comment: I was thinking more of the `|| [[ ... ]]` stuff

Comment: The `$'\0'` is not truncated in zsh. And that serves to prove that a `NUL` byte may be used in strings (well, ... , in some strings).

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Good to know about `zsh`, but this answer is about `bash` (the title clearly says `bash`, although the generic tags `sh` and `shell` create ambiguity). I've added a note at the top to clarify, which also contrasts `bash`'s behavior with that of `zsh` and also `ksh`.

Comment: Fantastic answer. So sad that bash goes with the horrible C zero-terminated string convention. Very ironic that this convention is so inconvenient in many cases...

Answer (score 16):

In bash, `$'\0'` is precisely the same as `''`: an empty string. There is absolutely no point in using the special Bash syntax in this case.

Bash strings are always NUL-terminated, so if you manage to insert a NUL into the middle of a string, it will terminate the string. In this case, the C-escape `\0` is converted to a NUL character, which then acts as a string terminator.

The `-d` option of the `read` builtin (which defines a line-end character the input) expects a single character in its argument. It does not check if that character is the NUL character, so it will be equally happy using the NUL terminator of `''` or the explicit NUL in `$'\0'` (which is also a NUL terminator, so it is probably no different). The effect, in either case, will be to read NUL-terminated data, as produced (for example) by `find`'s `-print0` option.

In the specific case of `read -d '' line <<< "$var'`, it is impossible for `$var` to have an internal NUL character (for the reasons described above), so `line` will be set to the entire value of `$var` with leading and trailing whitespace removed. (As @mklement notes, this will not be apparent in the suggested code snippet, because `read` will have a non-zero exit status, even though the variable will have been set; `read` only returns success if the delimiter is actually found, and NUL cannot be part of a here-string.)

Note that there is a big difference between

```
read -d '' line
```

and

```
read -d'' line
```

The first one is correct. In the second one, the argument word passed to `read` is just `-d`, which means that the option will be the *next argument* (in this case, `line`). `read -d$'\0' line` will have identical behaviour; in either case, the space is necessary. (So, again, no need for the C-escape syntax).

Comment: Great answer. It's a code style thing. I write `$'\0'` to make my intentions clear.

Comment: @rici when you said "no need for the C-escape syntax" are you saying that `read -d ''` has the same result as `read -d $'\0'`? In effect, both result in read using the NUL char as the line-end character?

Comment: @JohnMarkMitchell: Yes. There is absolutely no detectable difference between `''` and `$'\0'`. (And, I believe, there is really no difference internally either.)

Comment: No, `$'\0' is precisely the same as '': an empty string` that's not true (always), and in fact, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @binaryZebra: Remembering that we're talking about bash, would you care to provide an example which shows different behaviour?

Comment: @rici I could provide some `\0` examples: `printf 'ab\0cd' | od -An -vtx1`. And we should be aware that in zsh `a="$(printf 'ab\0cd')"; echo "$a"` will contain an ASCII NUL byte (with value `0x00`). And I believe that zsh is an useful shell which should not be completely discarded.

Comment: @rici The question is (also) about the effect of `$'\0'` on `read`, which is that `read` will read up to the next `$'\0'` (yes, a mouthful, but correct). That is absolutely **not** the same as saying that `read` will read till the next "empty" byte.

Comment: @binaryzebra: your printf example does not use `$'\0'`; in that casethe backslash and 0 are being passed to printf. I have nothing against zsh, which as you say is useful, but this question is clearly about bash, and so is my answer. There is no such thing as an empty byte, and I have not used that phrase. So I stand by my claim that in bash, `''` and `$'\0'` are indistinguishable.

Comment: @rici Would you be so kind to tell me what character value is used by `read` to split the input on this command: `read -r -d $'\0'`, thanks.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, which claim made prior in this comment thread would the answer to that question refute?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The statement that `'' and $'\0' are indistinguishable` fails to acknowledge the fact that a '0x00' is used to split the input by the command of `read` presented as example by the OP, and therefore may confuse the reader. A `read -r -d $'\0'` is more explicit about that IMhO.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, ...whether or not a NUL byte is or is not used to split the input has no bearing on whether the conventions are distinguishable -- that is, whether the implementation of `read` has any way to tell which of two relevant possibilities it was passed (thus *distinguishing* between the two).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The command read has no way to distinguish between `$'\0'` and `''`, yes, that's technically true. The same as tabs are irrelevant to commands but very useful to users to format code. And humans reading the command (and translating that to "an idea") will get and read different text and may get different "meaning" in both cases. They may even get the incorrect meaning.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, I agree that different human encodings of a given parse tree or argument string can have pertinent differences for readability, but if we interpret "distinguishable" as a term of art (which is how I read rici's statement above, expanding "to bash" as "to the bash interpreter", ie. how the parse result is viewed *by bash itself*), human-readability matters are not pertinent to the factuality of rici's claim.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If both are in-distinguishable, then either could be used to represent the exact same technical value. It is then a matter of "personal expression" to make intentions clear.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, indeed so. (Does the above comment attempt to refute any prior statement or claim in this thread?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Only that it is better to write `read -r -d $'\0'` instead of `read -r -d ''` and that that is not  in-distinguishable to the reader.

Comment: I think it's understood at this point that we agree to disagree as to which kind of potential misunderstanding we prefer our code to promote. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How you write your code is entirely your choice. But the fact remains that the two ways to write the code are distinguishable.

Comment: Not distinguishable **to bash**, ie., the interpreter itself, no. I consider any other interpretation a misreading so severe as to be presumptively deliberate and thus a strawman argument, though it would be rici who could speak definitively to the intent of the language at hand. (If it had been "in bash" rather than "to bash", that could be reasonably interpreted as meaning-to-humans rather than meaning-to-the-parser, but the use of the word "to" is entirely clear).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The first sentence of this answer does say `**In** bash, $'\0' is precisely...`. Also state: `There is absolutely no point in using the special Bash syntax in this case.`. It has become patently clear that both ways are **not** equivalent. It also state (incorrectly) that `if you manage to insert a NUL into the middle of a string, it will terminate the string`. If a string with an inserted `NUL` is assigned to a variable, the NUL is **removed**, the string is **not** terminated. Just three of the mistakes included.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, your claims are not fully correct. For instance, re: "If a string with an inserted NUL is assigned to a variable" -- it depends on exactly where it's coming from. `foo=$(bar)` will eliminate a NUL in the output of `bar`, but that's not the assignment doing the elimination but the command substitution. For the assignment, the NUL **does** in fact terminate the string.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, ...as for repointing your existing critique against the first sentence rather than the context to which you initially asked that it be applied, if we wanted to quibble about different types and meanings of "equivalent", we could do that, but I honestly can't see much value in the exercise; absent seeing eye-to-eye with you on that point, I can't agree with your claim that that first sentence is in fact inaccurate.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, ...I will grant you only that "there is absolutely no point" could indeed be amended to "there is absolutely no non-stylistic point", or similar.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Could you be so kind as to provide an example of `For the assignment, the NUL does in fact terminate the string.` (not a command substitution of course).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am not claiming anything about the `In bash`, just telling you that you are incorrectly stating that a `to bash` was used when in fact it was not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy By the actual experience on this thread I believe that there is no point if you grant anything.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: To reiterate what Charles said: it is the _command substitution_ that _strips_ the NULs, not the _assignment_. Here's an assignment that does cut off at NUL: `printf -v var 'a\0b'; printf %s "$var" | cat -v`.  I would also like to take a moment to reflect on how your combative attitude, cantankerousness, and ad-hominem attacks have really been unpleasant to witness and endure. What could have been an interesting and fruitful dialog (and was, between the rest of us) turned sour.

Comment: @mklement0 The only bad comment was done by Charles Duffy: `pedantry and hair-splitting`, not me.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Yes, it outputs `a`, which means that it _cuts off_ (at the first NUL). If it stripped, you'd get `ab` - which is what you do get with `var=$(printf 'a\0b')`, because the command substitution _strips_.

Comment: @mklement0 The only reason it has not been "fruitful" is because you are only centered on making me changing my opinion (which is correct anyway), instead on trying to understand **what** is being said. An example is your division on: "the rest of us" and "you". So, in your words you imply that: I am the odd one. What do you want me to do on that? To say: yes I am the only wrong one sorry everyone? No, that is not what should happen, and will not happen.

Comment: @mklement0 Ah, sorry, I swaped the understanding of the words. I understand what you mean, now. I'll get back to this latter.

Comment: @mklement0 I do not know how we walked into a disagreement about cut, strip, terminate or ignore a NUL, nor what I was thinking at the time, but I actually misspoke when I said that: `If a string with an inserted NUL is assigned to a variable, the NUL is removed, the string is not terminated.` I do know the opposite is true. And that is clear in my rewritten answer.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, I consider pedantry and hair-splitting to be worthwhile endeavours -- making sure that peoples' understanding of a topic is accurate, precise and well-defined is a valuable pursuit when working in a field where details matter. Yes, I used those words poking fun at myself, but it was intended to be in a good-natured manner.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy All is well that ends well. I'll take all in a good-natured manner and move forward. :-)

Answer (score 5):

It is technically true that the expansion `$'\0'` will always become the empty string `''` (a.k.a. the *null* string) to the shell (not in zsh). Or, worded the other way around, a `$'\0'` will never expand to an ascii **`NUL`** (or byte with zero value), (again, not in zsh). It should be noted that it is confusing that both names are quite similar: `NUL` and `null`.

However, there is an aditional (quite confusing) twist when we talk about `read -d ''`.

What `read` **see** is the value `''` (the null string) as the delimiter.

What `read` **does** is split the input from stdin on the character `$'\0'` (yes an actual `0x00`).

---

## Expanded answer.

## The question in the tittle is:

> In a bash script, what would $'\0' evaluate to and why?

That means that we need to explain what `$'\0'` is expanded to.

What `$'\0'` is expanded to is very easy: it expands to the null string `''` (in most shells, not in zsh).

But the example of use is:

```
read -r -d $'\0'
```

That transform the question to: what delimiter character does $'\0' expand to ?

This holds a very confusing twist. To address that correctly, we need to take a full circle tour of when and how a NUL (a byte with zero value or '0x00') is used in shells.

#### Stream.

We need some NUL to work with. It is possible to generate NUL bytes from shell:

```
$ echo -e 'ab\0cd' | od -An -vtx1
61 62 00 63 64 0a                           ### That works in bash.

$ printf 'ab\0cd' | od -An -vtx1
61 62 00 63 64                              ### That works in all shells tested.
```

#### Variable.

A variable in shell will not store a NUL.

```
$ printf -v a 'ab\0cd'; printf '%s' "$a" | od -An -vtx1
61 62
```

The example is meant to be executed in bash as only bash printf has the `-v` option. 
But the example is clear to show that a string that contains a NUL will be cut at the NUL. 
Simple variables will *cut* the string at the zero byte.
As is reasonable to expect if the string is a C string, which must end on a NUL `\0`. 
As soon as a NUL is found the string must end.

#### Command substitution.

A NUL will work differently when used in a command substitution.
This code should assign a value to the variable `$a` and then print it:

```
$ a=$(printf 'ab\0cd'); printf '%s' "$a" | od -An -vtx1
```

And it does, but with different results in different shells:

```
### several shells just ignore (remove)
### a NUL in the value of the expanded command.
/bin/dash       :  61 62 63 64
/bin/sh         :  61 62 63 64
/bin/b43sh      :  61 62 63 64
/bin/bash       :  61 62 63 64
/bin/lksh       :  61 62 63 64
/bin/mksh       :  61 62 63 64

### ksh trims the the value.
/bin/ksh        :  61 62
/bin/ksh93      :  61 62

### zsh sets the var to actually contain the NUL value.
/bin/zsh        :  61 62 00 63 64
/bin/zsh4       :  61 62 00 63 64
```

It is of special mention that bash (version 4.4) warns about the fact:

```
/bin/b44sh      :  warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
61 62 63 64
```

In command substitution the zero byte is silently ignored by the shell.
It is very important to understand that that does not happen in zsh.

Now that we have all the pieces about NUL. We may look at what read does.

#### What `read` do on NUL delimiter.

That brings us back to the command `read -d $'\0'`:

```
while read -r -d $'\0' line; do
```

The `$'\0'` shoud have been expanded to a byte of value `0x00`, but the shell cuts it and it actually becomes `''`.
That means that both  `$'\0'` and `''` are received by read as the same value.

Having said that, it may seem reasonable to write the equivalent construct:

```
while read -r -d '' line; do
```

And it is technically correct.

#### What a delimiter of '' actually does.

There are two sides of this point, one that is the character after the -d option of read, the other one, which is addressed here, is: what character will read use if given a delimiter as `-d $'\0'`?.

The first side has been answered in detail above.

The second side is very confusing twist as the command `read` will actually read up to the next byte of value `0x00` (which is what `$'\0'` represents).

To actually show that that is the case:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create a test file with some zero bytes.
printf 'ab\0cd\0ef\ngh\n' > tfile

while true ; do
    read -r -d '' line; a=$?
    echo "exit $a"
    if [[ $a == 1 ]]; then
        printf 'last %s\n' "$line"
        break
    else
        printf 'normal %s\n' "$line"
    fi
done <tfile
```

when executed, the output will be:

```
$ ./script.sh
exit 0
normal ab
exit 0
normal cd
exit 1
last ef
gh
```

The first two `exit 0` are successfully reads done up to the next "zero byte", and both contain the correct values of `ab` and `cd`. The next read is the last one (as there are no more zero bytes) and contains the value $'ef\ngh' (yes, it also contains a new line).

All this goes to show (and prove) that `read -d ''` actually reads up to the next "zero byte", which is also known by the ascii name `NUL` and should have been the result of a `$'\0'` expansion.

In short: we can safely state that `read -d ''` reads up to the next `0x00` (NUL).

## Conclusion:

We must state that a `read -d $'\0'` will expand to a delimiter of `0x00`.
Using `$'\0'` is a better way to transmit to the reader this correct meaning.
As a code style thing: I write $'\0' to make my intentions clear.

One, and **only one**, character used as a delimiter: the byte value of `0x00`
 <sub>(even if in bash it happens to be cut)</sub>

---

**Note**: Either this commands will print the hex values of the stream.

```
$ printf 'ab\0cd' | od -An -vtx1
$ printf 'ab\0cd' | xxd -p
$ printf 'ab\0cd' | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "'
61 62 00 63 64
```

Comment: ++ for a much improved rewrite. Re choosing between `$'\0'` and `''` in `bash`:
There is no good solution to this problem: the choice is between (a) using `-d $'\0'` to make the `read` command self-documenting, which carries the price of mistakenly suggesting that `$'\0'` creates a NUL, and (b) using `read -d ''` to reflect what's going on _technically_, which carries the price of obfuscating how the `read` command functions. Personally - and it really is a matter of _preference_ - I prefer (b), because the mistaken belief that `$'\0'` creates a NUL can become a problem in many situations.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, it took a while to get it really clean. I have no problem with anyone using `$'\0'` or `''` as long as it is understood that there is no reason to mindless ban or segregate the other possible use.

Answer (score 1):

`$'\0'` expands the contained escape sequence `\0` to the actual characters they represent which is `\0` or an empty character in shell.

This is BASH syntax. As per `man BASH`:

> Words  of  the  form `$'string'`  are  treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Known backslash escape sequences are also decoded.

Similarly `$'\n'` expands to a newline and `$'\r'` will expand to a carriage return.

Comment: I... think this is the first time I've *ever* downvoted an anubhava post for inaccuracy. (`$'\0'` does not in fact evaluate to a NUL; it would, if they could be represented in C strings, but they can't).

Comment: Completely agree with both of you @CharlesDuffy and  mklement0. I have removed inaccurate parts but other answer explains it better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy NULs are well represented in zsh strings. If we make a simple test inside zsh: `a="$(printf 'ab\0cd')"; echo "$a" | xxd -p` produces `61620063640a`. Yes, a NUL exists in the middle. So: some C created code (well; 66.4% of zsh code anyway) may correctly process NUL containing strings.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, in *bash*, NULs coming from command substitutions are removed. Yes, it's possible to use Pascal strings (which is to say, strings with length metadata stored out-of-band rather than represented with a terminator) in software written in C, but it's extra work (can't use standard-library string-handling calls), and bash (the shell tagged in the question) doesn't do it.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, ...which is to say that by "C strings" I didn't mean "the only kind of string that can be represented in C", but "the kind of string conventionally referred to with 'C Strings' as a term of the art", which happens to also be the only kind of string the C standard library string manipulation functions work with. ("Pascal strings" are, likewise, often used in languages much, much newer than Pascal, but they still have that name).