# Read a null-terminated string from binary into variable using od in MINIX ash

Tags: bash, minix, ash

Rather rookie question but I got stuck with it for a while: I have a problem to read and parse a string that is stored in hard drive at the address that I know ...

I don't know the length of the string, only it's maximum length say `n`. It has been written into `n`-buffer initiated with zeros so its hexdump is like `xx xx xx xx 00 00 00 00 00` where `xx`'s are hex for proper string chars.

So as I know the address of the string, I copy it into binary `tmp` file using using `dd if=<hd> of=tmp` (with proper bs/count/skip to get the `n` bytes of the buffer). Then in bash (or rather in MINIX ash to be precise) I try to use `od` to parse it and read into variable but I cannot get rid of spaces/nulls:

```
name=$(od -Anx -tc tmp)
echo $name
```

and I get `J O H N \0 \0 \0 \0 \0` instead of simply `JOHN`

Comment: You could try passing it through `strings` if it is string-like.

Comment: `name=$(od -Anx -tc <(sed 's/\x00//g' tmp))`

Comment: Can you paste here the output of `cat -e tmp`?

Comment: `cat -e tmp` output: MAGDA^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple trick which relies on the fact that [bash strings cannot contain a NUL character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19229243/262683):

```
name="$(cat tmp)"
echo $name
```

Comment: It works well under bash .. but I was a imprecise at the start (sorry for that) - I need it to work under MINIX 3 shell (ash). Ash produces empty string for that. Anyway, good to know the trick, thanks

Comment: I find "...using **bash** and od" to be quite "*precise*" :)

Comment: No worries. Can you try `name=$(cat tmp)`? I think that should work in `ash` as well...